# Specifying JSON dynamically in React Native

Tags: json, react-native

I'm trying to get specific JSON files according to the prop passed to the page.

```
var data = require('./../mock-data/items/item_' + this.props.id + '.json');
```

But this fails and gives the following error message.

***Unhandled JS Exception: Requiring unknown module "./../mock-data/items/item_2.json". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager.***

What is causing this? Any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requiring modules dynamically is not allowed in React Native. You need to create a switch/method/if/object that will require the file you need.

// GOOD

`<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />`

// BAD

`var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />`

// GOOD

`var icon = this.props.active ? require('./my-icon-active.png') : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />`

More info here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html